# Using react-web-tabs, is there a way to switch tabs AND navigate to hashed ID via click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

I'm building a conference website using three of these tabs (#speaker, #talks, #schedule). I think it is fair to want interactions between the tabs, here are a couple use cases that I cannot seem to solve.

1. From the #talks tab, I click on the bio hash - #johnsmith.  This id exists within the page, but since I don't first switch tab to #speakers, nothing renders.
2. If I want to reference a specific talk and email someone the url:  https://website.com#speaker_name the tabs won't open, and nothing but the tabs render.

The problem is compounded by the fact that when I click on an anchor tag href using a '#id', I must reload the page for it to fire.

I feel like there should be some way to pass a parameter when changing the tab or *something*... I'm in a tough spot because I'm rolling out   code, but need this functionality badly.

Here is the actual open-source repo - https://github.com/kernelcon/website.  The code I'm referencing can be found in src/pages/Agenda/.

Here is some example code.

Agenda.js

```
  <Tabs defaultTab={this.state.defaultTab}
    onChange={(tabId) => { this.changeTab(tabId) }}
    vertical={vert}>
    <TabList vertical>
      <Tab tabFor="speakers">Speakers</Tab>
      <Tab tabFor="talks">Talks</Tab>
    <span>
      <TabPanel tabId="speakers">
        <Speakers />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel tabId="talks">
        <Talks />
      </TabPanel>
    </span>
  </Tabs>
```

Talks.js

```
changeTab(id) {
  window.location.reload(false); 
}

getTalks() {
  // Order Alphabetically
  const talksOrdered = speakerConfig.sort((a,b) => (a.title > b.title) ? 1 : ((b.title > a.title) ? -1 : 0));
  const talks = talksOrdered.map((ele, idx) => {
    const twitterUrl = ele.twitter.replace('@', '');

    return (
      <div id={ele.talk_id}
        key={idx}
        className='single-talk'>
        <div className='talk-title'>{ele.title}</div>
        <div className='talk-sub-title'>
          <div className='speaker-name'>
            <a onClick={() => {this.changeTab(ele.speaker_id)}}
              href={`#${ele.speaker_id}`}>{ele.speaker}</a>
          </div>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing this by sending `#tab_title/speaker_name`, then adding a `componentWillMount` lifecycle method and function in the main tab file like below.

```
componentWillMount() {
  const defaultTab = this.props.location.hash ? this.props.location.hash.split('#')[1] : 'schedule';
  this.setState({
    defaultTab: defaultTab
  });
  this.handleHashChange();
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.handleHashChange);
}
handleHashChange = () => {
  // given `#speakers/dave` now you have tabName='speakers', speakerHash='dave'
  const [tabName, speakerHash] = window.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('/');
  const tabNamesToWatchFor = [
    'schedule',
    'speakers'
  ];

  if (tabNamesToWatchFor.includes(tabName)) {
    this.setState({
      defaultTab: tabName,
      // pass this.state.speakerHash to <Speakers/> and use this for scrollIntoView in componentDidMount
      speakerHash: speakerHash
    });
  }
}
```

Next, I went to the individual tab (in this case `Speakers.js`) and added a `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` method to help scroll to the speaker itself.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.handleScrollToSpeaker(this.props.speakerHash);
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.speakerHash !== this.props.speakerHash) {
    this.handleScrollToSpeaker(this.props.speakerHash);
  }
}
handleScrollToSpeaker = hash => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      const ele = document.querySelector(`#${hash}`);
      if (ele) {
        ele.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start',  behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    }, 500)
}
```